# Use Phonegap with Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am planning to use phonegap to convert my web app to a native app with iPhone camera support. I have used jquery-mobile and rails helpers in my Rails app views. What is the easiest way to covert my web app into a native app with communication to the server? I am not worried about the responsiveness of the app as it is at a prototyping stage.

Please give pointers to tutorials or how to change my rails helpers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about the application performance and are not distributing it to the App Store then you can simply load your web app in the PhoneGap container (rather than a local index.html file served from the file system on the phone) and it should all work. You would do this slightly differently for each platform at the moment. Are you interested in any one in particular?

Comment: I am not concerned about performance and don't plan to distribute on app store. Planing to run it on an iPhone as a webapp - I do need to use its camera, hence the need for Phonegap. It would be perfect if I can follow the PhoneGap container approach. Ideally, I would like to make only minimal changes to my mobile webapp. Can you point me to a good resource to get started? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the iPhone native [Picup app](http://picupapp.com/) to take pictures and post to my server. This way I continue to have a webapp which calls the Picup app when camera and photo functions are needed.